# How to use VM imageID's in Azure Policy?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Azure has a number of built-in VM agent related policies. E.g. for installing the dependency agent, log analytics agent or the new Azure Monitoring Agent via a deployifnotexists effect.
Examples are:

- Configure Linux machines to run Azure Monitor Agent and associate them to a Data Collection Rule
- Configure Windows machines to run Azure Monitor Agent and associate them to a Data Collection Rule

Since we are only using CIS images from the marketplace our VM's are ignored in the policy evaluation.
Both these initatives contain a parameter for additional virtual machine image ID's. It accepts an array of image ID's something like: listOfWindowsImageIdToInclude or listOfLinuxImageIdToInclude.
However when I inspect the properties of my VM (ImageReference) the property ID is always empty:

[cis image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOEvu.png)

[windows image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMcVC.png)

If I query the marketplace it shows something like this:

[cis images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19om3.png)

I already included those Ids in the intiative parameter but without success.

All these built-in policies evaluate a custom image ID as follows:

```
      "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageId",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfLinuxImageIdToInclude')]"
          },
```

But like I said the image ID of these marketplace images is empty...

Comment: So don't filter by imageID, Did you try filtering by **imagePublisher**, **imageOffer**, or **imageSku**?

Comment: Well this publisher center-for-internet-security-inc (CIS) is not in policyEvaluation included neither the imageOffer and imageSKU so that does not work. My question is more why is the imageReferenceID of marketplace images seem to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Following this documentation ([Apply policies to Windows VMs with Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/policy) and [Apply policies to Linux VMs with Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/policy))

Could this policy be:

```
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "in": [
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        ]
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
              "in": [
                "center-for-internet-security-inc"
              ]
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
              "in": [
                "cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-11"
              ]
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSku",
              "in": [
                "cis-ubuntu2004-11"
              ]
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageVersion",
              "in": [
                "latest"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work, please share your JSON policy

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response but then I would have to create about 8 custom policies whilst there are built-in policies which should do the job. Like I included in the original post there are 2 built-in initiative each containing 4 built-in policies which all work according for instance: Configure Linux Machines to be associated with a Data Collection Rule and Configure Windows Machines to be associated with a Data Collection Rule

Comment: You can use Wildcard (Ex: cis*), you can use " anyOf " to allow more than one image. Please, read the documentation that I shared, there are some useful examples.